# How to go to the n'th character, not byte, of a file?

Tags: vim, utf-8

In `vim` one can get to the 5th byte of the file with the following command:

```
:goto 5
```

However, in a UTF-8 text this could be the 5th, 4th, or even 2nd character in the file. How to go to the 5th **character**, not byte, of a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start from the beginning of the buffer, and use `search()` to match N characters. The only pitfall is considering the newline characters, too. Here's a custom `gco` mapping that does this:

```
function! s:GoToCharacter( count )
    let l:save_view = winsaveview()
    " We need to include the newline position in the searches, too. The
    " newline is a character, too, and should be counted.
    let l:save_virtualedit = &virtualedit
    try
        let [l:fixPointMotion, l:searchExpr, l:searchFlags] = ['gg0', '\%#\_.\{' . (a:count + 1) . '}', 'ceW']
        silent! execute 'normal!' l:fixPointMotion

        if search(l:searchExpr, l:searchFlags) == 0
            " We couldn't reach the final destination.
            execute "normal! \<C-\>\<C-n>\<Esc>" | " Beep.
            call winrestview(l:save_view)
            return 0
        else
            return 1
        endif
    finally
        let &virtualedit = l:save_virtualedit
    endtry
endfunction
" We start at the beginning, on character number 1.
nnoremap <silent> gco :<C-u>if ! <SID>GoToCharacter(v:count1 - 1)<Bar>echoerr 'No such position'<Bar>endif<Bar><CR>
```

Note that this counts just one character for the CR-LF combination in buffers that have `'fileformat'` set to `dos`.

Comment: This is absolute magic, Ingo! Thank you very much, I always learn from your posts.

Comment: Hannah just splits the ages of my own two daughters, and as you know the name is used in Hebrew as well as Japanese. If you and your loved every visit Israel, there is a cold beer waiting for you and two friendly girls who would love to play!

Answer (score 1):

What about just `gg0` to go to the first character in the file, then `4l` to go work your way 5 characters in? I suppose this may fail if you have empty lines or if you want to count linebreaks.